# Enabling ECDH KeyExchangeAlgorithm in Windows Schannel while disabling CBC based ciphersuites

Tags: encryption, tls, windows, key-exchange, ciphers

On our Windows Servers, we have disabled the following key exchange algorithms in registry

```
SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\ECDH 
SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS
```

This leaves us with only 2 available Cipher Suites that could be offered in the Client Hello (*0x9E & 0x9F*), which has broke some of our applications.

If we re-enable ECDH, it would allow the weak CBC cipher suites as well (e.g *TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384*)

Is there any method to disable CBC based ciphers suites, while allowing the secure GCM based cipher suites of ECDH-ciphersuites like *TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384*
?

Comment: If you only enable GCM cipher suites in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls#configuring-tls-cipher-suite-order-by-using-group-policy , do you get what you want?